# how to do subquery or backlink query in realm react-native?

Tags: react-native, subquery, realm

The problem I'm trying to solve is this.  If I have product, I'd like to know what other products I can purchase as a combination that's on-sale.  If this were MySQL, I'd set up my tables and queries like so:

```
t_product: product_id, product_name
t_combination: combination_id, on_sale
t_product_combination: combination_id, product_id

// what other products should I buy along with my product_id == 1 to get a good deal?
SELECT product_id
FROM t_product
WHERE product_id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM t_combination_product
    WHERE combination_id IN (
        SELECT combination_id
        FROM t_combination
        WHERE on_sale = 'yes'
        AND combination_id IN (SELECT combination_id FROM t_combination_product WHERE product_id = 1)
    )
)
```

I tried to do this in realm react-native as shown below:

I have two collections: Product and a Combination, set up as follows

```
class Product {};
Product.schema = {
    name: 'Product',
    primaryKey:'productId',
    properties: {
        productId:'int',
        product:'string'
    }
};

class Combination {};
Combination.schema = {
    name: 'Combination',
    properties: {
        onSale: {type: 'string'},
        products: {type: 'list',objectType:'Product'},
    }
};
```

What I want to do is given that I have `Product.productId=1`, I want to find all other products that belong to Combinations that have `Combination.onSale='yes'` and `Product.productId IS IN (Combination.products )`.

This is the query I tried to do in realm with react-native:

```
let queryFilter = "ANY Combination.onSale = 'yes' AND Combination.products = 1";
let data = realm.objects('Product').objectsWhere(queryFilter);
```

But when I run this, I get the error

> undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'realm.objects('Product').objectsWhere(queryFilter)')

If I remove the `objectsWhere(queryFilter)`, then it just returns me the list of all Products that hasn't been filtered.

So it seems I'm using objectsWhere incorrectly? How do I fix this to find a list of all products that are onsale if purchased with product 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had

```
class Product {};
  Product.schema = {
    name: 'Product',
    primaryKey:'productId',
    properties: {
        productId:'int',
        product:'string'
        combinations: {type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'Combination', property: 'products'}
    }
};
```

Backlink queries are not yet supported, so I think what you have to do is something like this:

```
let queryFilter = 'productId = 1';
let data = realm.objects('Product').filtered(queryFilter);
let combinations = data.combinations.filtered('onSale = true');
let linkedProducts = [];
for(let i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
    linkedProducts.push(combinations[i]);
}
// linked products should contain what you need
```

Comment: Man, your query syntax was totally off, and the method is called `filtered` not `objectsWhere` :D Where'd `ANY` come from?

Comment: thanks I was following some ObjectiveC code as an example because I couldn't find anything else.  I tried your solution but I get the error `Property 'onSale' is not a link in object of type 'Combination'`.  I've checked my model and Combination.onSale does exist. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm populating the Combination.products property+array when populating the Combinations collection.  This means that I don't have to explicitly populate the Product.combinations property+array while populating the Product collection right?  Product.combinations will automatically know to reference Combinations.products?  I populate Product collection first, then I populate the Combination collection along with Combination.products afterwards.

Comment: `Product.combinations will automatically know to reference Combinations.products? ` yes   ---- although you SHOULD be able to make query across linking objects, I'll ask the Realm-JS team what I'm messing up here, see https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/343#issuecomment-344997426

Comment: I have updated my answer, because apparently Realm-JS doesn't support backlink queries yet.

Comment: ah man....ok....the workaround you suggested is what I have as a bandaid solution.  And it takes about 3-5 seconds to execute the query against 30000 combination records...I was hoping back link queries would perform better